# Select element not working properly HTML 5 (IE10)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I have one line of code that only works most of the times

```
 $('[name=' + results.rows.item(i).id + ']').get(0).selectedIndex = selIndex;
```

for some reason when I run it in Internet Explorer 10 it does not correctly change the selected index to the the one I provided. It as if it is being reset or not changed at all. I try the same piece of code in chrome and it works perfectly fine 100% of the time. Is it a bug?

The html is built with a XSLT template, so all the value property are set to the same

```
<!-- dropdown input template -->
<xsl:template match="DataField[@ControlType='DropDown']" priority="1">
<td colspan="{DisplayOptions/@ColSpan}" location="{DisplayOptions/@Column}">
  <div class="divider">
    <xsl:value-of select="FieldOptions/@DisplayName "/>
  </div>
  <div class="divider">
    <select name="userInput_{@Name}" class="dropbox" select="">
      <option>
        <xsl:value-of select="FieldOptions/@LookupType"/>
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <xsl:apply-templates select="SubDataFields"/>
</td>
```

**UPDATE 3**
Here is the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/564Yh/13/). It seems to work fine there though? Although it is not exactly the same code it his similar enough. I am thinking it has to do with rendering to early or to late?

**UPDATE 2**
I notice that when I debug I have a jquery exception thrown

```
Exception was thrown at line 4224, column 4 in http://localhost:50297/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js
Exception was thrown at line 4242, column 4 in http://localhost:50297/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js
```

I wonder if this is what is causing the code not to work. The error does not show when I debug in the other browser only in IE10.

**UPDATE**
The problem use to happen in Safari and Opera, but after I hosted on my server everything works fine. Until I try it on IE10. Now it doing the same thing where if I refreshed the selected index is changed to -1. I check the value before and it is 0 and that value I am assigning is right but after the assignment it is changes any ideas?

Comment: have you tried storing `'[name=' + results.rows.item(i).id + ']'` as a variable, and then using it that way? `$(theVariable).get(0).selectedIndex = selIndex;` And perhaps throwing an alert to help debug `alert(theVariable);`

Comment: Tried it, and no luck I also tried using `var domName = 'Select[name="' + fieldId + '"]';`. You guys think it's an IE bug? I also posted it on Microsoft IE Development support page.

Comment: @user1878558 You should set up a little jsFiddle demo, with the generated HTML and your jquery code added.